# How to use find command to execute two conditions in linux

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

I am trying to delete files (log files) which are more that 5 days old and I need to keep one specific file without deleting, I tried it using

```
find . -type f -mtime +5 ! -name 'test2' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

But this is not successful. The OS im using is Centos 7.

Comment: an alternative could be to echo the results of `find . -type f -mtime +5` to a file, remove 'test2' from the list and then use a for loop to delete all items listed in the file.

Comment: How is it "not successful"?  Does it delete all files including `test2`?  No files at all?  Do you get an error message?
Also please explore the possibility of using `logrotate` for this, if your requirements are at all complicated.

Comment: It works on my system linux mint 17.2 , can you please show us the output of `ls -la .`

Comment: @Dave, he's running centos so has GNU versions of the tools available: `find . -type f -mtime +5 -print0 | grep -Zzv '^test2$' | xargs -0r rm -f`

Answer (score 2):

As you can see I've created for testing the following structure:

```
mkdir test && cd test && touch file1 file2 file3 lol test2
touch -t 200805101024 file*
```

obtaining this:

```
ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Oct 13 18:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 phphil phphil 4096 Oct 13 18:09 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      0 May 10  2008 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      0 May 10  2008 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      0 May 10  2008 file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      0 Oct 13 18:09 lol
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      0 Oct 13 18:09 test2
```

And after executing your correct command:

```
find . -type f -mtime +5 ! -name 'test2' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

The situation is as expected:

```
ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Oct 13 18:09 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 phphil phphil 4096 Oct 13 18:09 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      0 Oct 13 18:09 lol
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      0 Oct 13 18:09 test2
```

**Edit : Finding informations about commands, or command params :**

When I'm not sure about the behaviour of a certain command and/or parameter, I proceed as follow :

```
man find | less
```

then you can search what you are looking for inside the manual of the command as follow:

- type `/`
- write your search terms which I beleave they are `-mtime`
- then you can go to the next occurrence of your search terms by typing `N` , or to the previous one by typing `n`

I have find out this interesting informations:

> ```
>    -mtime n
>           File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.  See the comments for -atime to understand how  round‐
>           ing affects the interpretation of file modification times.
> ```

Comment: You did not test what the question is.

Comment: What you mean? you talking about the "two conditions", I think he was talking about 1) 5 days old files 2) except a file 'test2'

Comment: Oh you right! I got it, I will do it and fix the answer

Comment: @lese thank you, when we put -mtime +5 does it count from the current system date and time both from the time it is executed to 5 days back? 
sorry I'm bit new to linux.

Comment: I think this is an other question and should not be related with the acceptance of the answer : )  , anyway I have edit my answer in order to help you find what you looking for

Comment: @lese yes your answer was helpful. :) thanks.